# How to validate a tab-delimited file to see that it matches the original sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, csv

There has been some issues when saving some excel files into tab delimited txt files where the columns have been shifted and also sometimes some data has been erroneous. Is there some good way of validating the tab-delimited txt file to check that each column matches the columns in my workbook sheet?

This is how the file is saved

```
FileExtStrInput = ".txt": FileFormatNumInput = 20

xWorkSheet.Copy
xFile = FolderName2 & "\" & "saved_txt " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy hh-mm-ss") & FileExtStrInput
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNumInput
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

I would like to make a sub which I can call and it checks the column values one column at a time to make sure that it matches my workbook sheet. Then just post a MsgBox stating that validation was done successfully or if it failed.

Comment: If you just want to know if the Excel file is different from the state when it was exported, then just export it again (so it is definitly the same). Or if you just want to check if it is the same but keep it different, export/save it again (to a different/temporary file) and calculate a hash (eg MD5, SHA1) over both text files. If the hashes are the same both text files are the same. That would actually be much easier and faster than checking each value.

Comment: Would it not be better cure the illness, instead of the symptom? I mean, I can't recall ever seen *... issues when saving some excel files into tab delimited txt files where the columns have been shifted and also sometimes some data has been erroneous.*. Can you give some more information on this? An example file would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share any of the data files used to achieve this. They are files with up towards 130000 rows of data and about 20 columns. Regarding data error, I have not seen this issue myself and I am also skeptical. However I cannot rule out there beeing a compatability problem, the file is saved from xlsx or Office 365 to a xls file 97-2003 and then into a Tab delimited file. So I want to make sure the tab delimited file has the same values as the original xlsx file (no rounding problems etc). That erroneous output is impossible is tbh also a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *"no rounding problems etc"*? If there are formulas in your sheet it will **always** round the values at some point (it is impossible not to). You must give at least some example data that represents the actual issue (see [mcve]). It is impossible to help on a hypotetical issue. We need something more concrete. • Otherwise the question is a way to broad to answer it.

Comment: The file is completely imported from another system. The only functions in excel is reference to another field. For example a price that needs to be represented twice. The first value is for example (Cell P3) 12345,23 and the only function used would then be =P3 in a cell later in the row. So with no rounding problems I am thinking if there are any numerical differences between different versions of Excel

Comment: Well maybe the total approach makes no sense then. Instead of checking all values why don't you just perform the duplication of the data in the source file itself? I mean importing data from somewhere to Office 365 than convert it into an ancient 97-2003 format and then convert it again into a tab delimited file? Really? That doesn't look like a solid approach *at all* and there might be more incompatibilities than you are able to check. Instead perform the changes directly on your source file (tab delimited). This way you control and know what changes are made.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for. In the grand context of things the reason the file is converted in this manner is because of demands on file versions from other applications. The approach made no sense to me either, and I will attempt to change it for the better. The discussion we have had here has helped me a lot in grasping the problem. Again thank you.